# How to change PhantomJS version

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am learning PhantomJS for scraping. I started to incorporate CasperJS. When I run CasperJS and the filename I get back

```
CasperJS needs PhantomJS v1.x
```

How do you change the PhantomJS version to use CasperJS? Is there an easier way to scrape a website that is heavy javascript?

I used cheerio and require but they only get static html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is shown if you try to use PhantomJS 2.x with a CasperJS version <= 1.1-beta.

#### use different PhantomJS once

If you also have PhantomJS 1.x on your system, you can simply change the executable like this in the command prompt.

cmd.exe:

```
C:\path> set PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=C:\path\to\phantomjs198.exe

C:\path> casperjs script.js
```

terminal:

```
$ export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/phantomjs198
$ casperjs script.js
```

You can also use "phantomjs198" instead of "/path/to/phantomjs198" if it is in PATH.

#### Update CasperJS

The other way would be to use the CasperJS from the master branch on GitHub ([docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git)). It works rather well in my experience and supports PhantomJS 2.x (and PhantomJS 1.x).

Comment: I have a similar problem as i have version 1.9.0 in my machine already installed . I have the binary file of 1.9.2 but don't know how to remove the older version to work with this newer version . I followed your steps but wasn't able to find any solution. please let me know some other way to do it. thnx.

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala I don't know how you installed it, so I can only guess. If you installed it through npm, then you can also remove the global phantomjs package. If you installed it by putting it into PATH and don't know anymore where the file is, then you can find out with `which phantomjs` and simply remove the file. Please don't use 1.9.2 instead. You should really use 1.9.7, 1.9.8 or 2.0.0.

Comment: Thank you . But the problem with the 1.9.7 and upper is the zip files are with errors and i am not able extract them successfully. Either they may be corrupt of anything else but i am not able to extract them. So if you can provide me a good source , it would be really helpfull to me. thnx. I have downloaded from the following link which gives corrupted source . http://phantomjs.org/download.html