# Run Casperjs with specific version of Phantomjs

Tags: macos, npm, phantomjs, casperjs

In response to this issue where newer PhantomJS is 10x slower:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14066

I want to run CasperJS with an older version of PhantomJS.  I have globally installed both with npm.

`sudo npm install -g casperjs`

`sudo npm install -g phantomjs@1.9.8`

`$ phantomjs --version`

`1.9.7`

`$ casperjs --version`

`1.1.0-beta5`

However when I run my Casper scripts my previously properly (but slowly) running script throws:

`Error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('Email').value = email')`

How do I properly link casperjs to phantomjs?

Comment: *"I have globally installed both with npm."* - There's your problem. "Install" CasperJS from git and PhantomJS as prebuilt package.

Comment: Do you mean `npm install -g git+https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git` ?

Comment: No, I mean that you shouldn't use npm at all. I've always had problems with CasperJS and PhantomJS installed through npm on Windows or Linux. It's better to follow [this guide](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git). They seem to have improved installation with 1.1-beta4, but I haven't tried it. [My setup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30847220/1816580) works rather well. No idea, if this is different in OS X.

Comment: Following that guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094647/install-casperjs-from-git-i