# Install CasperJS from git

Tags: git, macos, casperjs

From the docs, the process is:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
$ cd casperjs
$ ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

After doing this, my error is as follows.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ casperjs --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/casperjs: is a directory
```

Comment: did you try going to `/usr/local/bin/` folder and run the command `./casperjs --version`

Comment: returns `1.1.0-beta5` so I guess the linking isn't working for some reason?

Comment: ok now try from any outside folder. However, give `./` before casperjs.

Comment: so just `./casperjs --version`? -> `-bash: ./casperjs: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok. Looks like you're good to go ahead with the further instructions of casperjs installation, only you have to add the path /usr/local/bin/casperjs to your environment or run casperjs from that path.

Comment: There is no further instruction for osx. http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: You can go ahead to install phantomjs and write your first script as it says here: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git